# Sql Transcation Query to Linq Query in Wcf Rest Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am converting one sql Transcation query to Linq query . I have done little bit and i am trying to write rest of the linq query but i am confused ..

Here is the ADO.NET Code with Sql Query.

```
 public bool RewardToCurrentTranscation(MoneyTransfer mopneyTransfer)
        {
            int amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount);
            int amount1 = System.Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount1);

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            string sql = "select Account_Balance from Reward_Account_Details where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cn.Open();

            //amount = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            if (amount > 0)
            {
                int b;
                int b1;
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                SqlTransaction trans;
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cn.Open();
                trans = cn.BeginTransaction();

                cmd1.Connection = cn;
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Transaction = trans;
                cmd1.CommandText = "update Reward_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance-'" + mopneyTransfer.Amount + "' where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No + "'";
                b = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd1.CommandText = "update Current_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance+'" + mopneyTransfer.Amount1 + "' where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Account_No + "'";
                b1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (b == 1 && b1 == 1)
                {
                    trans.Commit();
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        //Create the SqlCommand object
                        //Create the SqlCommand object
                        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Reward_Account_Wdraw", con);
                        //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                        cmd3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Add the input parameters to the command object
                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No);
                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Name", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Name);
                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", mopneyTransfer.Amount);


                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort_Code", mopneyTransfer.Sender_Sort_Code);
                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcation_Type", mopneyTransfer.Transcation_Type);
                        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", mopneyTransfer.Date);

                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Current_Account_Dposit", con);
                        //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Add the input parameters to the command object
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Account_No);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Name", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Name);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", mopneyTransfer.Amount1);


                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort_Code", mopneyTransfer.Receiver_Sort_Code);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcation_Type", mopneyTransfer.Transcation_Type1);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", mopneyTransfer.Date1);




                        //Open the connection and execute the query

                        con.Open();
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true;
                        //con.Close();
                    }

                }
                else
                    trans.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

So far i have done this much with Linq ...

```
public bool MoneyTranfer(MoneyTransfer mopneyTransfer)
    {


        int i = Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount);
        int j = Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount1);

        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities ctx = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
        {

            var foundAccount = (from a in ctx.Current_Account_Details where a.Account_Number.Equals(mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
                                select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

            using (var dbContextTransaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var acctDetails = (from a in ctx.Current_Account_Details
                                   where a.Account_Number.Equals(mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
                                   select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

                if (acctDetails != null)
                {
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                      }
                else
                {
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am confused on this code ..

```
 cmd1.CommandText = "update Reward_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance-'" + mopneyTransfer.Amount + "' where Account_Number='" + mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No + "'";
```

Can any one help me how to complete the rest of the query in linq

Comment: LINQ doesn't do transactions. It's for reading data.

Comment: is there solution for this problem ?

Comment: No it's by design. You should only use LINQ for reading data. Updating data using ADO.NET is perfectly fine. If you want something more advanced, look into entity framework.

Comment: ok.thanks very much

Comment: Also be aware of SQL injection, use parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: You may also want to look at Dapper [link](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) as a lightweight alternative to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your using you should issue another query like this:

```
var rewardAccount = ctx.Reward_Account_Details
    .Where(r => r.Account_Number = moneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
    .FirstOrDefault();

rewardAccount.Account_Balance -= moneyTransfer.Ammount;
```

Since you got the Reward_Account_Details from your HalifaxDatabaseEntities context, calling SaveChanges will save this change also.

**EDIT**

You do not need to explicitly open a transaction. EF will do it for you autmatically. See following code and edit it to your requirements.

```
public bool MoneyTranfer(MoneyTransfer mopneyTransfer)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount);
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(mopneyTransfer.Amount1);

    try
    {
        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities ctx = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var foundAccount = (from a in ctx.Current_Account_Details where a.Account_Number.Equals(mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
                                select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

            var acctDetails = (from a in ctx.Current_Account_Details
                               where a.Account_Number.Equals(mopneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
                               select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

            if(acctDetails == null)
                return false;

            var rewardAccount = ctx.Reward_Account_Details
                .Where(r => r.Account_Number = moneyTransfer.Sender_Account_No)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            rewardAccount.Account_Balance -= moneyTransfer.Ammount;

            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        //Maybe log it.
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Shall i call save change method after this rewardAccount.Account_Balance -=  line ??

Comment: I have an variable called amount . I am comparing it inside the if statements.  Where i need to add this variable like (amount >0)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything rather than asking constantly how to code your business logic?

Comment: That you rod its was great help for me